# how can i assign application to open mail attachment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Hi i want to do Ios app which should open an exact format of attachment which will be received by mail.
so i receive an email with attachment, i open it and click long to the attachment and i want to see option to open with my app.

how can be it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the document interaction controller

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304

"For example, an email program might use this class to allow the user to preview attachments and open them in other apps. ..."

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is in this link, register you application to open the attachment in mail/Safari.

[Supporting Open In... menu item in my app for iOS Mail And Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/supporting-open-in-menu-item-in-my-app-for-ios-mail-and-safari)