# iOS - Add menu item to Safari "Open with"

Tags: objective-c, ios, safari

I'm new to iOS development - How do I create a Safari extension that adds a new item to the "Open with" menu (the same menu where I can bookmark the page)? I'd like to share the page URL that the user is currently viewing with a third-party app.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Supporting Open In... menu item in my app for iOS Mail and Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597), which has a nice thorough tutorial-like answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Xcode, go to your project settings, then choose your target.  In the Info tab, you would add a Document Type which will associate it (doc, xls, txt, etc) with your application.  If you open the item in safari, you will be presented with an option to open it in your app.  In recent versions of mobile safari, I believe a bar appears at the top of the document presenting you with this option as opposed to appearing in the 'Add Bookmark' popover.

[Here is some detailed information.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403)