# How to launch my iPhone app via Safari URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Supporting Open In… menu item in my app for iOS Mail And Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/supporting-open-in-menu-item-in-my-app-for-ios-mail-and-safari)

I'm working on an application that will download files from the Internet, for further use.

How do I launch my own app when a link is pressed on Safari?

For example, when a .pdf file link is shown in safari the user clicks it and the file is downloaded. After that there is the suggestion to "Open in", followed by a list of possible applications, like iBooks. I want my app to be displayed among these options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look into associating the PDF file type with your app.

The answers to [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) pretty much covers it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading the indicated thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to open your app then see [Custom URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

But associating file type to your iPhone applications is different than custom URL scheme. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application) greatly describe it

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading the indicated Thread.