# How to get ppt file from iPhone mail and safari?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, info.plist

I want to read `.ppt` files from the iPhone mail app. I have already done read the PDF file using this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/supporting-open-in-menu-item-in-my-app-for-ios-mail-and-safari). It's working fine, and they used this code for generating the menu in the mail app:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF Document</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Powerpoint</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

It's working fine. I googled the problem, but if someone could guide me how to detect `.ppt` files from mail attachments, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use PPT files, you must declare your intent to conform to its UTI, which means simply changing the bit about `com.adobe.pdf` to `com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt`.  Easy.

For all intents and purposes, also change `CFBundleTypeName` to `Powerpoint`.

Comment: i update my code now. now i can get only ppt file now pdf in won't work. kindly tell me where i'm doing wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you shouldn't have duplicated the entire `CFBundleDocumentTypes` entry like you have for `pdf`s and `ppt`s.

Rather, you only need one of these such blocks, and you simply want to add another `CFBundleTypeName` to the .

So, your plist should look like this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF Document</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Powerpoint</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Notice that I didn't end the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array until I had added both entries.