# Open image/PDF through system or other apps with own app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm wondering if there is anyway to tell the system(eg photos or adobe app) to open/share a file with own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **yes** you can do that, by adding file extension and mime type for files you want to open with your own app.

Long answer: [Supporting Open In... menu item in my app for iOS Mail And Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/supporting-open-in-menu-item-in-my-app-for-ios-mail-and-safari)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you'll just need to know the URL for the app you want and iOS can handle the rest:

```
// This will open in Safari
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

// This will open in Yelp
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yelp:///search?term=burritos"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

There are also built-in objects to do various things without leaving your app.  For example, [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html) describes how to access a user's photos without having to actually switch apps.