# Account manager integration - Android vs iOS

Tags: android, iphone, ios, accountmanager

I am Android developer, but I need to answer to some questions regarding what is possible with other platforms and I wonder what iOS offers that is comparable to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html. I found https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html but I can not understand the full range off possibilities.

Questions:

- How Account Manager used in iOS??
- In Android it is possible to share tokens for a service, does iOS have the same feature
- Is there a centralized API or is this solved app-2-app?
- Are there any security concepts available connected to this (restrict access to tokens to certain apps and so on)

Happy for short and quick responses!
// Jonas

Comment: I have the same Issue. What I can use in place of Account Manager(Android) in iOS

Comment: I got solution of this problem. Let see my answer

Answer (score 5):

There is not AccountManager type feature available in iOS. Yo need to add and implement Setting.bundle for your preferences as similar account manager will do in Android.
Please check this links:

[LINK 1](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html)

[LINK 2](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-add-setting-bundle-to-your-app.html)

[Apple Doc for Setting.bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Comment: Ok, good. So the settings bundle would be a way to store the auth token for my app but.there is no platform enabler for sharing the "single sign on doing session " as in android where the account manager api can distribute tokens to apps. If this is a incorrect summary correct me - I am trying to understand the differences in platforms...

Comment: Yes you can distribute tokes by using UIDocumentInteractionController.
Check  <<https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html>>

Comment: You can also distribute tokens like instagram do while sharing image from one app to instagram
check <<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146924/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-prevent-airdrop-in-the-open-in-sheet>>

Comment: This link helps u. I think u need the same that i suggest 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942597/supporting-open-in-menu-item-in-my-app-for-ios-mail-and-safari